# Is the product of strictly quasiconcave functions quasiconcave?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have two functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ which are strictly quasiconcave (since they have positive derivative before a certain point and negative derivative after that point. The points where derivative become zero can be different for each of the functions). I want to ask whether $f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)$ will be a quasiconcave function or not? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried some examples?  Almost any example will do.

Comment: @RobertIsrael will almost any example show that the product is quasiconcave or not?

Comment: @RobertIsrael is there any example that I can try?

Comment: Is $f(x)=-x^2$ strictly quasiconcave?

Comment: @kimchilover thank you for your example. I understand it now

Comment: If you say so.  Can you summarize your new understanding for us?

Comment: @kimchilover I just understood that product of strictly quasiconcave function is not necessarily quasiconcave. This i observed from your example of $f(x)=-x^2$ which is a quasiconcave function but $f^(x)$ is not a quasiconcave function. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: Frank, my impression is that you ask a lot of questions of this general sort. Allow me to suggest this. In convex optimization books like Boyd & Vandenberghe, the authors enumerate a variety of composition rules where functions can be combined while preserving convexity and quasiconvexity. If you have an idea for a "new" composition rule like this, and it doesn't follow trivially from the ones supplied by these authors, you probably ought to assume that it's not true. Because if it were, why would they not include it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  A simple example will suffice.  Consider the L 1/2 norm and a shifted L 1/2 norm.

Now, if two non-negative quasi-convex functions have the same optimal point, then the product is quasi-convex.  I think there are some other cases where this works.

Another question might be: is it possible to combine two quasi-convex functions into a new quasi-convex function.  And the answer is, yes it is!  Suppose that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are quasi-convex.  Then $f=\max(f_1,f_2)$ is a quasi-convex function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can your answer change if I say that the individual functions are positive?

Comment: @FrankMoses  I don't think so.  The example I gave with the L1/2 norms is such a case, and you can see that the product is not quasi-convex.

Answer (score 0):

The product of two positive CONCAVE or log-concave functions is quasi-concave. (Concave implies log-concave, and it is known that the product of log-concave functions is log-concave, hence quasi-concave). 
But the product of two positive quasi-concave functions need not be quasi-concave. Here's a simpler example: $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=9-14x+6x^2$, on the interval $[0,7/6]$. $f$ is increasing, $g$ is decreasing, both positive, but the product has a local max at $0.75$ and a local min at $1$.