# Is it a concave function of $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is an increasing function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ whose first derivative and second derivative are always positive. I want to know whether the following function will be concave or not $$g(x)=log(1+f(x))$$ $x$ can only take positive values and $f(x)$ is also positive always. Further, the double derivative of $f(x)$ is always positive (which means $f(x)$ is a convex function). Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, try $f(x) = x^2$ for example.

Comment: @dxiv But I think $g(x)$ is at least quasiconcave since $f(x)$ is an increasing function and $log$ is also an increasing function. What do you say?

Comment: That's not what you asked. Point of my comment was that $\,g(x)=\log(1+x^2)\,$ is *convex* on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @dxiv yes I completely agree with you. But do you think that $g(x)$ is not quasiconcave?

Comment: Any monotonic function is *both* quasiconvex and quasiconcave, so that much is fairly obvious, and you don't even need for $\,f\,$ to be convex, just increasing will suffice.

Comment: Repeating what I said in this comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581375/is-it-possible-to-say-that-product-of-strictly-quasiconcave-functions-is-a-quasi#comment5329241_2581375